# NumSharp Dot product between N-D array to 1D array throws an errpr

Tags: c#, arrays

I am using NumSharp for Neural networks in C#

When I forward I try to receive the dot product of the Neurons values(1-D array)
with the dot product of the weights(2-D array).

However, when I try to make a dot product of a 2-D array with a 1-D array it throws an error saying it cannot broadcast to a single shape.

As far as I remember numpy in python can work with that perfectly, so why can't NumSharp?

Moreoever, in the very docs it specifies a case of dot product between N-D array with 1-D array, as well as in the code (I may have taken a look in NumSharp's code and found and if statement that tests this specific condition)

I used debugging for both shape, dimensions, and the arrays themselves, the data it right, the dot product should have worked yet it didn't...

Has anyone else ever encountered it? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so apparently the way I distributed my matrices was wrong.
Instead of inserting a matrix, I inserted a vector that doesn't have the proper shape to get a DOT operation with the weight matrix.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by the author, the problem here is that NumSharp for some reason does not support Vector & Matrix dot product (even though NumPy does support this). So one dimensional inputs just don't work. Example in pseudocode:

```
var vector = // some NDArray of shape (1, x) or (x)
var matrix = // some NDArray of shape (x, n) 
var result = np.dot(vector, matrix) //<--- will throw error as described
```

My ugly hack around this was to create a fake matrix of shape (2, 1, x) to replace the vector. This was done using np.zeros and then setting the first row in the matrix to be the vector. Then we can do the dot product operation and take only the first row as the output we want.

```
var fakeMatrix = np.zeros(2, 1, x)
fakeMatrix[0] = vector // or fakeMatrix[0,0] if input vector shape is (x)
var result = np.dot(fakeMatrix, Matrix)[0]
```